# client.connect() failing unless I ping my ESP

Tags: esp8266

[EDIT] it seems like this has to do with my laptop's firewall settings rather than anything wrong with the ESP8266 [/EDIT]

I have a webserver on my laptop. When I do this on my ESP8266 (after the wifi has been connected)

```
while(!client.connect(laptop,port)) {
   Serial.println("Connecting...");
   delay(1000);
}
```

It loops forever. However, if I manually ping my ESP from my laptop, I initially get this

```
Pinging 192.168.1.7 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.7: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=255
```

And as soon as this happens, the ESP gets connected to the laptop, and all works fine.

So it seems to me like the client.connect is preventing the ESP from even registering to the network, and the pinging is somehow waking it up.

Comment: what if you ping something else instead?

Comment: tried that - it doesn't do anything

Comment: oh wait, you're right - if I ping something else, even an IP that does not exist, the ESP suddenly connects. OK this means there's something dodgy going on on my computer. Going to check if this happens with another device.

Comment: Just tried running the server from a raspberry PI, the ESP connects without trouble. There must be some firewall thing or something going on my laptop. Will check and revert

Comment: could not find the source of the issue - firewall is definitely off. I should try to get hold of another laptop (as opposed to PI) to check

Comment: Hmm, have you tried using a port above 1024? I once had trouble with that, but it's just an idea...

Comment: oh yeah that's one of the first thing I thought about, but I was already using 3000. I tried 8000, just in case that would help - no diff. And I should mention that when I ran the script on my PI, I had to do sudo otherwise it would not work.